# BigQuery: NodeJS client library timestamp error

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I am using the nodejs client to stream records to BigQuery, all is working fine apart from some error on my timestamp field, it seems to be appended with a bunch of digits.

**Error**:

`Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of 1551711230131000064 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch. The range of valid timestamp values is [0001-01-1 00:00:00, 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999]; error in writing field ts`

**Code to generate a** `timestamp`:

`const ts = Date.now().toString(); // tried without toString()`

**Code to store in BigQuery**:

```
function insertIntoTable(id, ts, url, domain) {
  console.log('ts: ', ts) // this logs the correct format 
  table.insert({
    id        : id,
    ts        : ts,
    url       : url,
    domain    : domain,
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

In this example I, logged the correct size timestamp -> `ts:  1551711230131`

The field is set as a `TIMESTAMP` type in the table.

Any idea on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this

```
Date.now() / 1000
```

Instead of this

```
Date.now().toString()
```

Comment: Thank you it works! But why?